# Can't Access to localhost:3030 - NodeJS Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

### Wanted Behavior

When my dockerized nodejs server is launched, i can access from my local machine to the address : http://localhost:3030

Docker console should then print "Hello World"

---

### Problem Description

I have a nodejs Server contained in a Docker Container. I can't access to http://localhost:3030/ from my browser

***server.js File***

```
const port = require('./configuration/serverConfiguration').port
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(port)
```

---

**DockerFile Exposes port 3000 which is the port used by the server.js File**

***DockerFile***

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /src

RUN npm install nodemon -g

WORKDIR /src
ADD app/package.json package.json
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm start
```

**I use a docker-compose.yml file because i am linking my container with a mongodb service**

***docker-compose.yml File***

```
version: '3'
services:
  node_server:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./app:/src/app"
    ports:
      - "3030:3000"
    links:
      - "mongo:mongo"
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

File publishes my container 3000 port to my host 3030 port

---

**New Info**
Tried to execute it on OSX, worked. It seems to be a problem with windows.

Comment: why would you expect to reach the port 3000 when you map it to 3030?

Comment: forgot to edit title i am trying to access 3030. Can't access it. Problem stays the same. Could you take this downvote away? This mistake correction doesn't solve the problem

Comment: try to change `const port = require('./configuration/serverConfiguration').port` to `const port=3000` and see if it works like that

Comment: @AriaGroult Did you specify the correct working directory ? As I can see from your code, you are running `npm start` under `/src` folder but it seems your js code is under `/src/app` ?

Comment: yes, what's the port value in ./configuration/serverConfiguration'? That's the one that matters.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Port Value is : 3000 in configuration file

Comment: @Yongfeng "start" script in package.json references to : "start": "nodemon -L app/server/server.js", i can see the server starting in my docker console that is not the problem.

Comment: Check the edit, this works on OSX, somehow it doesn't work on my windows machine -_-

Comment: restart docker in windows and try again. Check if your port is free (3030) and maybe you can show us also the `docker ps`

Comment: @Edwin Restarted docker, port 3030 is free, docker ps states : 2274cdc941a1        project_node_server   "/bin/sh -c 'npm sta…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3030->3000/tcp   project_node_server_1

Comment: by the status should be `Up About ..minutes` if you restarted the docker :)

Comment: I meant that i already tried this resolution before asking my question :p

Comment: @AriaGroult Maybe you just run into [a existing issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/204) which has not been resolved I think. A solution for that would be using [DockerProxy](https://github.com/Kymeric/DockerProxy)

Comment: Yeah that's probably it @Yongfeng anyway thanks for the help people

Comment: @AriaGroult did you resolve the issue? I think this might actually be something to do with `nodemon` as without `nodemon` things work...

Comment: Yes well this was about docker toolbox whic never publishes on localhost. It publishes on the machine ip...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed localhost for the machine ip since i was using docker toolbox. My bad for not reading the documentation in dept

Comment: For context, if you are using the Docker toolbox you can find the IP of the docker daemon by running the Docker QuickStart application (should be one of the first things displayed in the shell). You can also change it back by changing the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.